# Is there a difference between 場が凍る and 場が凍り付く?

Tags: word-choice, verbs, phrases

Is there a difference between 場が凍る and 場が凍り付く? Both seem to be in use. Both are 自動詞/五段活用. An example sentence by yours truly:

> 教室で先生に「お前何言ってんだ」って言っちゃって場が凍った
> 教室で先生に「お前何言ってんだ」って言っちゃって場が凍りついた

I have also heard 空気が凍る used in the same sense as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They basically mean the same, but 凍りつく gives an impression that the resulting, frozen state is more firmly set and doesn’t easily melt. I believe the “up” in “freeze up” adds a similar nuance compared to just “freeze”.

Comment: I think つく has more of a "sticky" feel to it.  In other words, the *freezing* will stick and stay.  (Basically what you said.) But, *up* doesn't really have this connotation.  I think "freeze up" is generally used with something you'd wish hadn't frozen, like the pipes in your house in winter.  I think *up* in this context gives more of a feel akin to using しまう in Japanese.

Comment: @A.Ellett: OK. Thanks. English is not my first language. How about "down"? Is "freeze down" even possible?

Comment: I wasn't really trying to *correct*; just add some thoughts of my own to what I felt was a pretty good answer on your part.  I understand the nuance you're trying to get at; I feel it strongly there with 凍りつく.  Unfortunately "freeze down" would sound a bit odd (unless you somehow were suggesting it was a deep frost that went deep *down* into the earth).  I think at best in English you'd have to throw in an adverb like "completely", like "the lake was completely frozen" (poor fish).  Or, "the river was frozen solid".

Comment: But the 場が凍りついた version is really more abstract in meaning, right.  And I don't think there's a good way in English of quite conveying the additional nuance of ついた here.  I think at best in English you can say "chilled the air"--yeah, I know it's 場 but....

Comment: I agree with @A.Ellett that "freeze up" refers to a situation where you'd wish something hadn't frozen, literally or figuratively. A simple figurative usage would be "I froze up on stage". I am wondering about しまう though. Doesn't しまう also carry the possible connotation that something is done completely, besides something that happens to one's dismay? I wonder how well that completeness jives with "freezing will stick and stay". Like can't 凍っちゃった mean "something completely frozen"?